# Html Helper - Second DropdownList is not validated

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, html-helper

I have a required annotation for property DepartmentId, and then I create view like this, “form1” display message that I must choose but “form2” did not do anything and submit, if I remove “form1”, “form2” will work normally. Is there any way to make "form2" validate too, thank you.

```
<form method="post" name="form1">
    @Html.DropDownList("DepartmentId",
        new SelectList(departments, "Id", "Name"),
        "Select Gender",
        new { @class = "form-control" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.DepartmentId)
    <button>Submit</button>
</form>


<form method="post" name="form2">
    @Html.DropDownList("DepartmentId ",
        new SelectList(departments, "Id", "Name"),
        "Select Gender",
        new { @class = "form-control" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.DepartmentId)
    <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: What does your model look like?

Comment: I'm guessing they will need to be in the same form?

Comment: Dear Balah: Thanks for your response.
No, The Problem is, I am making the single page application, so I need the Create Form and Edit Form for user to choose Department, Create Form (which I write before Edit Form) work normally, but Edit Form did't, they validate Html.TextBoxFor normally but @Html.DropDownList doesn't.